# Builing an Octomap from rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to build an Octomap from Kinect data using rgbdslam, but I'm experiencing some difficulties and hope someone here might be able to help me with that.
My setup:

- ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04
- rgbdslam downloaded and compiled as detailed in hxxp://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam (can't post proper link due to lack of karma)
- octomap(_server) from the Ubuntu-apt-packages (ros-groovy-octomap*)

I'm launching rgbdslam using the provided rgbdslam_octomap.launch file, which remaps /rgbdslam/batch_clouds to cloud_in (I've checked). rgbdslam seems to work fine in its own window. I want to visualize the generated Octomap in rviz using the appropriate plugins for OccupancyGrid/Map, however, rviz doesn't display anything - so I must assume that the Octomap isn't built (properly or at all).

I listened to /rgbdslam/batch_clouds using rostopic echo and found out that I have to select "Send map" in the rgbdslam in order to cause activity on this topic - I see a batch of numbers being transmitted as soon as I select "Send map". However, Octomap still doesn't seem to do anything, judging by rviz. I also tried octovis, but to no avail.

Does anybody here have a clue for me as to what I'm doing wrong? Why does it seem like no octomap is being built when /rgbdslam/batch_clouds transmits data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77436/builing-an-octomap-from-rgbdslam/) by [onkel_keks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6546/onkel_keks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*EDIT:* I simply tried launching rgbdslam and octomap_server separately, and it worked. Octomap_server also didn't need my entire RAM this time. So it must be a problem with that launchfile. Thanks for the help!

*EDIT 2:* I'd like to mark this as the correct answer, but the system tells me I don't have enough "karma" to do that. So I have to leave it open. Unless somebody can tell me another way to close it.

---

Thanks for the answer,

I tried your suggestions with the following results:

- Neither occupied_cells_vis_array nor octomap_point_cloud_centers display anything in rviz.
- When visualizing /rgbdslam/batch_clouds (which is remapped to /cloud_in, see below), I see a colored pointcloud of the Kinect data.

I'm launching octomap via the pre-packaged launchfile rgbdslam_octomap.launch (included in the rgbdslam sources):

```
<!-- Launch octomap_server for mappingL: Listens to incoming PointCloud2 data 
    and incrementally build an octomap. The data is sent out in different representations. -->
<node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server" output="screen">
      <param name="resolution" value="0.005" />
      <!-- fixed map frame (set to 'map' if SLAM or localization running!) -->
      <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="map" />
      <!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup, accuracy) -->
      <param name="max_sensor_range" value="6.0" />
      <!-- Save octomap here on destruction of the server -->
      <param name="save_directory" value="$(optenv OCTOMAP_SAVE_DIR ./)" />
      <!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
      <remap from="cloud_in" to="/rgbdslam/batch_clouds" />
</node>
```

As you can see, /rgbdslam/batch_clouds is remapped to cloud_in in the last line.

What am I *supposed* to see when visualizing cloud_in? Was that colored point cloud the thing that is to be expected and if so, is there any other explanation as to why octomap doesn't produce any output?

Thanks again!

---

Originally posted by [onkel_keks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6546/onkel_keks/) with karma: 28 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) on 2013-09-10**:
Do you have a complete TF coming from "map" to your kinect frame ?

**Comment by [onkel_keks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6546/onkel_keks/) on 2013-09-10**:
I did a "rostopic echo /tf" and saw following TFs being broadcasted:

- camera_link -> camera_rgb_frame
- camera_link -> camera_depth_frame
- camera_depth_frame -> camera_depth_optical_frame
- camera_rgb_frame -> camera_rgb_optical_frame

I suppose that hints towards a problem with rgbdslam providing no "map" TF?
Also, my laptop gets really sluggish when I "Send Model", and I noticed octomap_server eats 2.6 GB of my RAM. (sorry for the terrible formatting, I don't know how to make it better)

**Comment by [uranor](https://answers.ros.org/users/7256/uranor/) on 2013-09-30**:
I am having the same issues, but I don't quite understand your edits in this answer. Did you get rgbdslam and octomap_server to work together? If yes, could you please explain how, i.e. using which launch files?
Thanks

**Comment by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) on 2014-05-28**:
This is also the issue I have, and I have checked both the /octomap.. topics and /rgbdslam/... topics give no results. Has anyone found a solution to the transform?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also create and save an octomap directly from rgbdslam, as the current version includes the octomap library. The GUI has the item `Data->Save Octomap` and there is a ROS service call (`rosservice call /rgbdslam/ros_ui_s save_octomap filename.ot`).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-09-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer, you need make the same process but you only need public the topic for  send the poindcloud to octomap, you need cal the service.
rosservice call /rgbdslam/ros_ui send_all
and you see in rviz and octomap_server

---

Originally posted by [dianita](https://answers.ros.org/users/8511/dianita/) with karma: 11 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1